# Add multiple nodes using XMLDocument C# xml

Tags: c#, xml

I am trying to add multiple element/node (Invoice node) in my XML.

Here is the xml structure: (Required Output)

```
<Request>
   <Operation>Testing</Operation>
   <Count>2</Count>
   <Params>
      <Invoice>     
        <field name="CustomerNo" value="20000" />
        <field name="Email" value="test2@yahoo.com" />
        <field name="Invoice" value="12345" />
      </Invoice>
      <Invoice>     
        <field name="CustomerNo" value="10000" />
        <field name="Email" value="test1@yahoo.com" />
        <field name="Invoice" value="54321" />
       </Invoice>
   </Params>
</Request>
```

Here is my code

```
int[] invoice = new int[] {1002,1003};
foreach (int i in invoice)
{
  XDocument xDocument = new XDocument(
    new XDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", null),
      new XElement("Request",
        new XElement("Operation", "Testing"),
        new XElement("Count","2"),                               
        new XElement("Params",
          new XElement("Invoice",
            new XElement("Field",
              new XAttribute("name","CustomerNo"),
              new XAttribute("value","10000")),
            new XElement("Field",
              new XAttribute("name","Email"),
              new XAttribute("value","testemail@yahoo.com")),
            new XElement("Field",
              new XAttribute("name","Invoice"),
              new XAttribute("value",i))))));   
   Console.WriteLine(xDocument);
}
```

The code above generates this:

```
<Request>
  <Operation>Testing</Operation>
  <Count>2</Count>
  <Params>
    <Invoice>
      <Field name="CustomerNo" value="10000" />
      <Field name="Email" value="testemail@yahoo.com" />
      <Field name="Invoice" value="1002" />
    </Invoice>
  </Params>
</Request>
<Request>
  <Operation>Testing</Operation>
  <Count>2</Count>
  <Params>
    <Invoice>
      <Field name="CustomerNo" value="10000" />
      <Field name="Email" value="testemail@yahoo.com" />
      <Field name="Invoice" value="1003" />
    </Invoice>
  </Params>
</Request>
```

I just want to loop the Invoice node part based on how many number of invoice in my array. I know I'm looping the entire structure of my XML, but I cannot find a way to insert my loop inside the XMLDocument.

Any help will be appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace the loop with LINQ:

```
XDocument xDocument = new XDocument(
new XDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", null),
  new XElement("Request",
    new XElement("Operation", "Testing"),
    new XElement("Count","2"),                               
    new XElement("Params", invoices.Select(x =>
      new XElement("Invoice",
        new XElement("Field",
          new XAttribute("name","CustomerNo"),
          new XAttribute("value","10000")),
        new XElement("Field",
          new XAttribute("name","Email"),
          new XAttribute("value","testemail@yahoo.com")),
        new XElement("Field",
          new XAttribute("name","Invoice"),
          new XAttribute("value",x)))))));
```

Comment: Hi @Selman, it did work! Woow. I did not think you can do that! Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Issue is that you are iterating the complete document in the loop

```
int[] invoice = new int[] {1002,1003};
List<XElement> eleList = new List<XElement>();

foreach (int i in invoice)
{
  eleList.Add(
            new XElement("Invoice",
            new XElement("Field",
              new XAttribute("name","CustomerNo"),
              new XAttribute("value","10000")),
            new XElement("Field",
              new XAttribute("name","Email"),
              new XAttribute("value","testemail@yahoo.com")),
            new XElement("Field",
              new XAttribute("name","Invoice"),
              new XAttribute("value",i)))
   );
}

XDocument xDocument = new XDocument(
    new XDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", null),
      new XElement("Request",
        new XElement("Operation", "Testing"),
        new XElement("Count","2"),                               
        new XElement("Params", eleList)));
```

Comment: Hi @ManishM, this is an alternative solution to the problem! Thank you!